# pdf issue when shown in an aspx page in a web browser

Tags: asp.net, pdf

I have a pdf file and i have shown it in web broswer like this,

```
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(sFileName);
  if (buffer != null)
   {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.Flush();
    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
   }
```

But my problem is when i am going to show the pdf in local server it is showing all the pages,but same code when run in live server it is showing some of pages blank.I have tested so many days for this and not found any result.

Please help for this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to put Response.Flush() after Response.BinaryWrite(buffer) ?

Comment: Also you may need to add Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=result.pdf") after ContentType

Comment: have a look at this link and the answers :

http://stackoverflow.com/q/848679/168371

Comment: Try Response.Buffer =true; Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=fiename.pdf") and add Response.End() after Response.BinaryWrite(); If you do not want to download file. Response.TransmitFile(@"......\aaa.pdf")

Comment: @Qorbani , can u please say why it is required to Response.Flush() at the end .I think that Response.Flush() will release any resource and Response.End() will cause terminate the buffering process to the Response.But my problem is first 5 pages is blank and others are as usual. I am confused. Thanks for ur Help

Comment: @mns , The Flush method sends buffered output immediately so client can start consuming it, so doing flush after Response.Clear doesn't make sense because there is nothing in buffer to flush! That's why I recommend doing flush after BinaryWrite :-) If you still have an issue I recommend changing your method of downloading and sending to Response.