# Retrieving jpeg's as BLOBS yields different results in Windows than OS X, is this normal or is it my code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am connecting to my MS SQL server (2008) where I have stored JPG's as BLOB files and am retrieving them in a single page (displayImage.aspx) which I then show on other pages to display the image.  This works great in all browsers on a Windows machine.  However, from the OS X machines there is extended data being shown in the browser and the pictures are not displaying.  (screenshot:http://i.imgur.com/133I8.png) Any suggestions?  Code is below:

```
string image = Request.QueryString["image"];

if (image == null){
    image = "no_image.jpg";
}


    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNECTIONSTRING"].ToString());

    objConn.Open();

    string sTSQL =

                        "SELECT [data] " +
                        "FROM [DBTABLE] " +
                        "WHERE filename = '" + image + "'";

    SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sTSQL, objConn);
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataReader dr = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["data"]);

    objConn.Close();
```

Comment: Are you perhaps not setting Resonse.ContentType to "image/jpeg" (or "image/png", etc. depending on the image type)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are not providing a MIME type with your response. If you do, the browser won't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding this line beneath the Response.BinaryWrite() line?  *(see below)*

```
Response.End();
```

Sounds like it worked for this other, possibly-related question: [Reading a binary file and using Response.BinaryWrite()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848679/reading-a-binary-file-and-using-response-binarywrite)  ...