# Asp.net text file upload and retreving from database

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

net file upload and following is code am using for reterving files like word and pdf and xsl but am not gettting text file properly   which is including the aspx code also please fild code below

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lbl = (LinkButton)sender;
        int idee = Convert.ToInt16(lbl.CommandArgument.ToString());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();            
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select Name, ContentType, Data from Data_Files where Id=@Id");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idee;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);
        if (dt != null)
        {
            Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Data"];
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString();
            if (dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString() == "application/vnd.ms-word" || dt.Rows[0]["ContentType"].ToString() == "application/vnd.ms-excel" )
            {
               Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
            }
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

{

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a binary file and using Response.BinaryWrite()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/848679/reading-a-binary-file-and-using-response-binarywrite)

Comment: Firstly, I can see multiple bad habits going in there... Secondly, WHAT?